# Performance drawback of tf.numpy_function?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, computation-graph

I'm using a `tf.numpy_function` to load a file in my tensorflow program.

I can't find sufficient information about the drawbacks of using numpy_function, would there be enough that it's worth the trouble of passing this function to tensorflow compatible code ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I am also interested in finding more information about this. There are `scipy.special` functions which are not available in tensorflow which I would like to use.